# use of class template requires template argument list and no appropriate default constructor

Tags: c++, class, templates, hashtable

I'm not sure where I did wrong. I'm attemping to pass the string name and key from the class wrap to class hashT

C2955 :'hashT': use of class template requires template argument list

C2512 : 'hashT' : no appropriate default constructor available

```
template<class T>
class hashT{
public:
    hashT(const int newKey, const string newName= "") :theList(newKey,newName){
         key = newKey;
         name = newName;
         theList.push_back(key);
         theList.push_back(name);
    }

    hashT & operator=(const hash &rhs) {
          if (this != &rhs) {
          key = rhs.getKey(); 
          name = rhs.getName();
          desc = rhs.getDes();
       }
       return *this;
   }


private:
   vector<T>theList;
   int key;
   string name; 
}
```

Class wrap

```
class wrap{
  public:
    wrap(){  myList = new hashT[1000];

    ~wrap(){ delete[]myList;}

    //getter
     hashT<class T> *getHashing() const{
        return mylist;
      }

     //setter
     void setNextHash(hashT<class T> *hashelement){
        mylist = hashelement;
      }

  private:
        hashT<class T> *mylist;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class `wrap` has multiple errors. `hashT<class T>*` that's not how you define a template as return type.

You'll have to write:

```
template<typename T>
hashT<T> *getHashing() const {
    return mylist;
}
```

Same for `setNextHash`.

You can't make template variables though, so you have only one way of defining `mylist`, making `wrap` a template class just like `hashT`.

Comment: And it's not possible to declare a member like `hashT<class T> *mylist;`

Comment: @Danh Jup forgot about that sorry :) Thanks